# Is it possible to control the filename for a Response from a Jersey Rest service?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Currently I have a method in Jersey that retrieves a file from a content repository and returns it as a Response. The file can be a jpeg, gif, pdf, docx, html, etc. (basically anything). Currently, however, I cannot figure out how I can control the filename since each file downloads automatically with the name (download.[file extension] i.e. (download.jpg, download.docx, download.pdf). Is there a way that I can set the filename? I already have it in a String, but I don't know how to set the response so that it shows that filename instead of defaulting to "download".

```
@GET
@Path("/download/{id}")
public Response downloadContent(@PathParam("id") String id)
{
    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis";
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin";

    Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);

    Document doc = (Document)session.getObject(session.createObjectId(id));

    String filename = doc.getName();

    ResponseBuilder rb = new ResponseBuilderImpl();

    rb.type(doc.getContentStreamMimeType());
    rb.entity(doc.getContentStream().getStream());

    return rb.build();
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add a ["`Content-Disposition` header"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) to the response, e.g.

```
rb.header("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=\"thename.jpg\"");
```

Comment: I can't append this string to _Content-Disposition_ header
`filename*=UTF-8''url_encoded_filename`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 31):

An even better way, which is more typesafe, using the Jersey provided `ContentDisposition` class:

```
ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.type("attachment")
    .fileName("filename.csv").creationDate(new Date()).build();

 return Response.ok(
            new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    outputStream.write(stringWriter.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                }
            }).header("Content-Disposition",contentDisposition).build();
```

Comment: ContentDisposition comes from `org.glassfish.jersey.media`/`jersey-media-multipart`, which you might not already have if you do JSON exclusively between client and server.

Comment: In Jersey 1.17. it comes from `com.sun.jersey.core.header.ContentDisposition`

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you aren't using the ResponseBuilder class, you can set the header directly onto the Response, which avoids any extra dependencies:

```
return Response.ok(entity).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefile.jpg\"").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
    @Path("zipFile")
    @Produces("application/zip")
    public Response getFile() {
        File f = new File("/home/mpasala/Documents/Example.zip");
        String filename= f.getName();

        if (!f.exists()) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(404);
        } else {
            Boolean success = moveFile();

        }

        return Response
                .ok(f)
                .header("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename="+filename).build();
    }
```

Here I find the solution to my problem. I appended the file name in response header.